# Flush HTML out of order

Tags: html, css, css-float

Is it possible to flush html out of order and for the browser to display things in order? I understand that I could probably leverage JS on the client side, but is it possible to do this with just CSS?

For example if my html ends up being flushed in the order:

```
<html><body>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>2</div>      
</body></html>
```

Is there any CSS I could have in place so the html shown on the page is:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tables as a possible solution:  http://jsfiddle.net/UJWP4/37/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="block">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="top">
        <div class="block">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="block">2</div>
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    display: table; 
    width: 100%; 
}
.top {
    display: table-header-group; 
}
.bottom {
    display: table-footer-group;
}
.middle{
    display:table-row-group;
}
```

however, this probably limits to 3 sections, unless you can fiddle with it and get more to apply.  other than that, i think js is the way to go

hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, he could also use positioning for this, but I think this is nonsense. And you can only sort 3 sections, with a lot more markup, then given in the example.

Answer (score 1):

No. You just have to use JS or any other programming language to do this, because CSS is for styling/haptic and HTML for structure.